# Argument of type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, promise

Before initializing a React App, I fetch the user's info in the localStorage. Then, thanks to his id, I start a socket connection with the server.

When passing the user's id to the socket function, typescript claims that:

> Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Here is my index.tsx file:

```js
const user = fetchUser();

if (user) {
  getNotifications(user);
}

ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And the fetchUser() function:

```js
export async function fetchUser() {
  try {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("MyAppName")) return null;
    const user = await jwt_decode(localStorage.MyAppName);
    updateUser(user);
    return user.id;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

How to fix this? If I remove the async/await it works, but performance-wise, is it ok to block the thread like this before initializing the app?

Comment: What do you mean by "*block the thread like this*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUser` is returning a promise as any function defined with `async`, which you are manipulating prior to its resolution. Because you're operating in a module global scope, you could do as follows, which would execute in non-blocking manner:

```
    getUser.then(user =>  {
       if(user) {
           getNotifications(user);
       }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('Error: ', e))
```

Comment: Nice solution! Given my usecase, would you recommend to fetch user and subscribe to notifications before initializing the app, or do it in a asynchronous way, like in your exemple?

Comment: np, I was addressing the specific issue presented, but where you invoke `getUser` and the notification subscription depends on more specific details of your implementation. Anywhere you invoke it, it will be async - the q is whether there is any reason you can't do this in your top level App component, using hooks/lifecycle methods to moderate? There are limited cases where I have had to place similar code in a global scope -- for example, in react native, to listen for background notifications after the app was killed.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'll do it in a useEffect inside <App/>, just above the browserRouter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `App` takes the notifications as a prop in some way.  We want to load the notifications asynchronously and allow the `App` to render.  Once the fetch is finished, the props for the `App` will change to include the notifications.  Depending on what your app is expecting, you can either pass an empty array of notifications, or you can also add some prop which serves as a flag, like `isLoadingNotifications`, so that you can know to render a spinner within the app instead of the notifications.

This all should be done *within* a react component.  Probably further down the tree, but for now lets just wrap your `App` inside an `OuterApp`.

```
interface Notification {
  /**... */
}

const OuterApp = () => {

  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState<Notification[]>([]);

  const loadNotifications = async () => {
    await fetchUser();
    if ( user ) {
      const notes = await getNotifications( user );
      setNotifications( notes );
    }
  }

  useEffect( () => {
     loadNotifications();
    // should probably have a cleanup
  }, [] );

  return (
    <App 
      notifications={notifications}
    />
  )

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <OuterApp />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a global state manager, so I don't need a state and props. Following your suggestion, I'll just add the getNotification to the fetchUser() function, and have a simple useEffect() inside <App/>, just above the broswerRouter.